# Ubuntu install IntelliJIDEA (running environment of Spark)

Tags: ubuntu

Ubuntu install IntelliJIDEA at the command line. The problem is：
Startup Error:Unable to detect graphics environment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup probably your JAVA_HOME.

Via terminal, set JAVA_HOME to where you install java:
in my case its below but yours will be different

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home
```

and then set PATH with the addition you provided for JAVA_HOME:

```
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

If that is not the case as you mentioned in the comments then probably its because
no DISPLAY var is set correctly...

Nothing to do with your graphics card.

Just correct your DISPLAY settings

The DISPLAY setting may be missing because you're perhaps trying to execute as root instead of your normal userid

Comment: I have already setup jdk correctly.The following is my settings:export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_91   export PATH=/usr/local/idea/idea-IC-143.2370.31/bin:${SPARK_HOME}/bin:${SCALA_HOME}/bin:${JAVA_HOME}/bin:/usr/lcoal/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/bin:$PATH

Comment: Could you please tell me how to correct DISPLAY settings? I am a new man and I'm not familiar with this piece. Thanks.

Comment: before you use any sudo command what is the output of       echo $DISPLAY    ?

Comment: I have no output for echo $DISPLAY

I am trying on WSL - Windows Subsystem for Linux

Answer (score -1):

I found that this seems to be an issue when I run intellij using `sudo` and it can't access the `$DISPLAY` environment variable. You can work around it by using `sudo -E`.